# Combine OpenMP and MPI

Tags: mpi, openmp, openmpi, hpc

I am working on a particle physics programm and want to parallelize it now on a cluster. I attended some HPC lecture so i managed to create parallel tasks within a node using OpenMP. This still does not scale good enough. 
Hence I want to use several nodes that use some message exchange via network while in one node i parallelize with OpenMP.

For instance, i only know about MPI but i have heard about something called OpenMPI as a combined approach. I would be thankful about good sources about such an approach, that are understandable for someone with no Background in HP computing. Also i would love to hear other suggestions regarding my idea.

Comment: I agree with most parts. That being said, MPI only might be faster than OpenMP even on a single node, especially if a node has a bunch of cores and several sockets. So if your computation does not fit on one node, you might want to focus on MPI only, and then do hybrid MPI+OpenMP to optimize even more.

Comment: @Zulan 1) thanks for the clarification. 2) same as 1). To 3) with it scales not good I wanted to State that my Problem is to big to be handled well on one node. Thats why i search for a Hybrid approach.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too broad for stackoverflow. You would need to show some specific code and specific points where your struggle. But to clear up your biggest misconceptions: 1) Open MPI is an implementation of MPI and has nothing to do with OpenMP. 2) Combining multiple paradigms for parallelism like MPI and OpenMP is often called hybrid parallelization. 3) You should first focus on making sure your application scales well with OpenMP and only go to MPI if it scales good but your shared memory system is too small to finish the task. (repost because of stupid typo)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thanks for pointing that out, that was really dumb typo - I hope the comment did not confuse further rather than clarifying things.

Comment: @roran_physician yes - if your OpenMP parallelism works well but problem is still to big, hybrid parallelization with MPI + OpenMP is certainly a good approach. Yet the question is unfortunately still too broad to be discussed here - unless you can narrow it down in some way.

Comment: My question is not really related to this specific problem. I only want some sources where I can learn to do hybrid parallelization. Do MPI & OpenMP Interfere in a way that can destroys my algorithm? @Gilles Gouaillardet does MPI really scale better on a SMP System? The message passing should also cause more overhead compared to OpenMP, at least from my insight into the topic

Comment: As usual, the right answer is *"it depends"*. OpenMP *"natural"* fork join model has inherent scalability issue (you get hit by Amdahl's law when the core count gets high) and you will generally suffer from NUMA effect (unless your data locality is perfect or you are running on a single NUMA domain node, and you generally don't). So yes, MPI might scale better on a single node compared to OpenMP, even if send/recv has obviously a much higher overhead than a simple memory access. My main point is since you need MPI anyway, keep it simple and make your app MPI only first and see how things go.

Comment: Okay i think i understand your point. I will just try and if something specific comes up i will write again.

Comment: It might just be a typo in your question, but note that OpenMPI is an open-source implementation of the MPI library and has nothing at all to do with OpenMP (which is a compiler-based way of doing threaded programming). This is a very unfortunate naming convention and causes endless confusion ...

Comment: @David Henty that is a good comment. When i asked i really thought it was a combination of both. But due to the answers and a look in my exercise Codes, i figured it out.